# get SQL code of orm query in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

i want to get sql code that generated by sails orm
it means if i use

```
MyModel.find({id:2}).exect()
```

i get

```
"SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE id=2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sails-mysql adapter, you can try to set `LOG_QUERIES` to `true` when you lift the app.

```
LOG_QUERIES=true sails lift
```

Hope it works !

Comment: Hi, when i use 'LOG_QUERIES=true sails lift'  my project is run but do not show any sql code in terminal

Comment: Same happened with mine.